# .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am planning to develop a new mvc website with .Net Framework 4.5. But I have to do some maintenance work for an already existing mvc website which is built on Framework 4.0. Will there be problems if I install Framework 4.5 in my machine and fix code and publish old website which is built on Framework 4.0

Answer (score 3):

You can install framework 4.5. It won't create any problems. Just make sure that your existing  projects framework should be 4.0 only

Answer (score 0):

No that's fine. You can have .NET Versions and Visual Studio Versions installed side-by-side without problems.

Answer (score 0):

One thing of note: make sure that the machine running the .NET 4.0 site can handle .NET 4.5 installation. 4.5 is an in place update and they have some hidden bug fixes in some of the 4.0 assemblies that can induce unnecessary risk into the system. Other than that it should be fine.